# How to send browser content like Images, CSS and JS using Node, Express to html over browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

Working on a project and trying to use `nodejs` and `express` to consume an API. Having issues though displaying the information.

When opened the `index.html` file directly with a browser, it displays perfectly. But when tried to do so with `node` and `express`, get the following:

[image: link to image of what is displayed with node and express]

`server.js`:

```js
var Access_token = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';

var AirTable = require('airtable');
var base = new AirTable({apiKey:Access_token}).base('BASE');
var TableName = 'TABLE_NAME';
var ViewName = 'Grid view';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.get('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(__dirname);
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || '3000', function(){
  console.log("Your app is listening to port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

This is what my files' directory looks like
[image: file tree]

What is happening and what should I do? It clearly shows the `index.html` but it never pulls the `css`, `scripts`, or `images`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to let Express know that requests to a specific URL will be for static assets in the respective folder, and not to try and route it itself. Add these lines before your listener:

```
app.use(express.static('css'));
app.use(express.static('fonts'));
app.use(express.static('img'));
app.use(express.static('js'));
```

Docs: [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Hi @esquew, thank you for the answer but even with these lines, it still can't seem to load/find the the css, fonts, imgs, or scripts. Do you have any other suggestion?  I Get this error:      Refused to apply style from 'http://50620d00.ngrok.io/css/animate.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to move towards single-page application as project grows or on learning new things.

use this in your `server.js` this will help you in multiple ways in long run.

```
const path  = require('path');

// Setup views directory, file type and public filder.
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// ejs is just like html, stands for Embedded JavaScript templates. 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// This will allow all your files in public folder available on browser.
// Files like JS, CSS, and Images
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
});
```

Folder structure:

```
1. public
├─ 1. css
|  ├─ 1. app.css
|  ├─ 2. bootstrap.min.css
|  └─ 3. jquery-modal.min.css
├─ 2. js
|  ├─ 1. app.js
|  ├─ 2. jquery-modal.min.js
|  └─ 3. jquery.min.js
└─ 3. logo.jpg
2. views
├─ 1. index.ejs
└─ 2. login.ejs
6. .gitignore
7. app.js
8. package.lock.json
9. package.json
```

All **[ejs](http://ejs.co/)** are just HTML with `.ejs` as extension in place of `.html`.

Answer (score 0):

adding to esqew answer, you should move all static files  inside a folter  (e.g. public) and implement app.use:

```
app.use('static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

from your code you reference it with static and in the file system the folder's name is "public"